# Checking if Array of strings contains Object keys

Tags: arrays, node.js, object

I have the following object:

```
{
  apple: 0,
  banana: 0,
  cherry: 0,
  date: 0,

and so on...
}
```

And an array of strings that are words from a cookery book.

```
[0] => "the"
[1] => "apple"
[2] => "and"
[3] => "cherry"
```

and so on...

I would like to iterate over the array of strings and add +1 every time the above keys are mentioned as a string? I've been trying to use object.keys however have been unable to get it working?

This is in node.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something nice and simple like this, which will increment absolutely all keys from the array of strings:

```js
let ingredients = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: 0,
  cherry: 0,
  date: 0,
  // and more...
}

let arr = ["the","apple","and","cherry"]

// loop through array, incrementing keys found
arr.forEach((ingredient) => {
  if (ingredients[ingredient]) ingredients[ingredient] += 1;
  else ingredients[ingredient] = 1
})

console.log(ingredients)
```

However, if you want to **only increment** keys in the `ingredients` object that **you set**, you can do this:

```js
let ingredients = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: 0,
  cherry: 0,
  date: 0,
  // and more...
}

let arr = ["the","apple","and","cherry"]

// loop through array, incrementing keys found
arr.forEach((ingredient) => {
  if (ingredients[ingredient] !== undefined)
    ingredients[ingredient] += 1;
})

console.log(ingredients)
```

Comment: The ingredients object and the array of words from the book are both in their own respective files within a function each. I have them logging to the console currently, how can I include them within what you have entered above. 

Is it as easy as making a new file using module exports and then assigning their function let ingredients() = ingredients?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle it using array `filter` and `some`:

```js
var fruits = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: 0,
  cherry: 0,
  date: 0,
};

const words = ["the", "apple", "and", "cherry"];

var filtered = words.filter(word => Object.keys(fruits).includes(word));
filtered.forEach(fruit => fruits[fruit] += 1);

// fruits
// {apple: 1, banana: 0, cherry: 1, date: 0}
console.log(fruits);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it using `reduce`.

```js
const words = ["the", "apple", "and", "cherry"];

let conts = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: 0,
  cherry: 0,
  date: 0,
};
const result = words.reduce((map, word) => {
  if (typeof map[word] !== "undefined") map[word] += 1;
  return map;
}, conts);
console.log(result);
```